# Writing a service in C: How to pass and process arguments to running service?

Tags: ubuntu, c

I want to write a service in C.

While this service is running in background and processing some information I need to grab the results from this service from other applications or from command line.

Background:
I need a C application/service due to performance issues. The UI will be implemented in a higher language like Java or C#/Mono on Linux. The C application will basically process data, which will come in from another source. The UI layer should be able to grab the results in a loop every few milliseconds for example and display it to the user. Also it should be possible to pause/start/configure the service from the Java application. Thats where the question begins.

How do I implement the service in C, so that it can respond to commands in runtime?

Thanks,
Eduard

Comment: This is _very_ generic and not at all Unix/Linux specific. In general you implement it the same way you would, for instance, in Java. However, in plain C the objects will be only in your naming conventions and the libraries are used a little differently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to separate a service and its UI, you need some kind of [IPC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication) mechanism to make them communicate. Several of these exist, but the standard on linux-based systems these days is D-Bus, which can be used to access a service written in C from a client written in any language that has D-Bus bindings (Java and Mono have them). Your service should provide a D-Bus service for the client to call. D-Bus also provides a way to autostart services. Stopping and configuring can easily be implemented.

I would not make your UI grab results every few milliseconds as humans can't process info that quickly. An update rate of 25-30 times per second should be more than enough.

Comment: Not to denigrate your answer (which is extremely clear and useful) but most humans I know can't even handle update at a "mere" 30 times per second.

Comment: That depends on how it's presented. I was assuming an awful lot and guessing that it would be some sort of graphical display that would still work when watching it as a movie, such as audio visualizations or simply moving graphs of whatever metrics that moove relatively smoothly.

Comment: Sounds like the answer I was looking for. Thanks!